# SQLite DB not created

Tags: android, database-design, android-sqlite

This code is not creating my database. I wanted to create a pre-populated table with some default values on creation of the table. Although no error while execution. Any help?

DatabaseHelper Code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String dbName = "whatever.db";
public static int dbVersion = 2; 

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE smart (UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("UID", 9);
    cv.put("NAME", "clear");
    db.insert("smart", null, cv);
    db.close();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS smart");

}


}
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dbHelper.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not properly created? I don't see any fatal issues...  Though you should re-create your table in `onUpdate()` by calling `onCreate(db);` after `"DROP TABLE ..."`.  Also you might want to use `"_id"` for the primary key since Android is fussy about this.

Comment: I checked in DDMS File Explorer, there was no database

Comment: Are you testing your app on the emulator, a stock device, or rooted device?

Comment: Where are you opening the database? I see you close it, but i think you might have to open it first, before adding your ContentValues thingy

Comment: @Entreco It should already be opened when constructor is called with the database name and I have tried entering values by calling different method and it works fine

Comment: Entreco, has a good point.  `onCreate()`, `onUpgrade()`, etc aren't executed until you call `getWritableDatabase()` do you do this?

Comment: I tried calling getWritableDatabase() but no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

in your DatabaseHelper:

```
public static String dbName = "whatever.db";
public static int dbVersion = 2;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE smart (UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS smart");

}
```

and in your Activity:

```
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("UID", 9);
    cv.put("NAME", "clear");
    myDB.insert("smart", null, cv);
    myDB.close();
```

or add this method in Database helper:

```
    public void save(int yourUID, String yourText)
{
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("UID", yourUID);
    cv.put("NAME", yourText);
    myDB.insert("smart", null, cv);
    myDB.close();
}
```

then code in your activity:

```
            DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    helper.save(12, "Clear");
```

I hope, I helped you.

Comment: Thanks but it will reset my tables in database everytime the application is launched but I only want these values to exist when the table is created for the first time

Comment: tables don't reset every time the application is launched, if you save some data in DB, it will be present there until you not delete them on not delete the app.

Comment: I mean everytime helper.save(12, "Clear") is called which try to add an extra record everytime the app is launched

Comment: if return to your code, you shouldn't close db in method onCreate in DatabaseHelper, remove db.close() from method, and Database will create. I checked this.

Comment: sorry, i forgot for this, you need to add this line (dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); )  to code in Activity:
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);                    
dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();                               
dbHelper.close();

Comment: I just found out yesterday not to use db.close in oncreate(), moreover i don't need to close it anywhere since android will close it for me when app is exited. Apart from that I also saw that OnCreate() creates the records but does not show on DDMS unless the table is changed/updated again.

Comment: hmm.. it is a bad practice not close Database, because you can get a android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Comment: I always closed my cursor and i think database is closed when i call helper.close() right?

Comment: hm.. I am not sure, because I never used helper to close DB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this without using sqliteopenhelper

in your activity class

```
private SqliteDatabase Dbname;
Dbname =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(YourDbname, MODE_PRIVATE, null);//inside oncreate()

String createTable = "CREATE TABLE smart (UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT);";
db.execSQL(createTable); 

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("UID", 9);
cv.put("NAME", "clear");

db.insert("smart", null, cv);
db.close();
```

Comment: yes this worked but I would prefer using SQLiteOpenHelper class for a better structure and understanding.